# How to print out specific letters within a String in Java

Tags: java

I have been set a task to print out the 2nd, 3rd and 4th letter of a name within a String variable.

So for example the name is John and I want to print out the letters 'o, h and n only'

I was wondering if there is a specific method which I can use to carry out this task, if not what is the best approach to take?

Comment: Consider the .charAt() method of the String class, and use a loop initialized appropriately. The substring() method of String is also a possibility. Read the javadocs in the String class.

Comment: java has a lot of documentation [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) You can usually find what you want with little effort. [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

Comment: `System.out.println(variable.substring(1));`

Comment: You need to try this first by yourself and post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** as @KevinO pointed out, determining whether the name length or 4 is smaller solves issues that would cause exceptions. I updated to incorporate this input. 
Depends on how you're trying to print it. You can use a `for` loop and iterate starting at the 1st index of your `String name` like so:

```
String name = "John";
for(int i = 1; i < Math.min(name.length(), 4); i++){
    System.out.print(name.charAt(i));
}
```

Sample Run:

> run:
>   ohn
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

You could print out the`Character` one at a time like:

```
System.out.print(name.charAt(1)); //print character at index 1
System.out.print(name.charAt(2)); //print character at index 2
System.out.print(name.charAt(3)); //print character at index 3
```

This might be unsafe because you're not sure if the name will in be in fact at least 4 `Characters` long.
Sample run:

> run:
>   ohn
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Or perhaps the easiest way which is also safe, you could print it out using `String.substring()` which takes in a range, like so:

```
    System.out.println(name.substring(1, Math.min(name.length(), 4)));
```

This results in:

> run:
>   ohn
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: .substring(1, Min(name.length(), 4)) avoids the last problem of String length. The first solution doesn't stop at the 3rd printed character (it has name.length() but the question was character 2,3,4 only) if I read the question correctly.

Comment: @KevinO, right, incorporated your input into my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the name always has at least 4 letters in it, this code will work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = "JOHN";
    System.out.println(name.substring(1,4));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using charAt function on String . The following version of code should do what you are asking for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "John";
    if (input != null && input.length() > 1) { 
               System.out.println(input.substring(1, Math.min(input.length(), 4)));     
    }
}
```

Comment: This can work, but it is verbose and hard to maintain. Furthermore, it will print in a stacked column rather than on the same line. (Meed to use print not println).

Comment: @KevinO code edited to meet your concerns. We have to check length to avoid StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: yes, the StringIndexOutOfBounds is a concern. But consider `if (input != null && input.length() > 1) {
            System.out.println(input.substring(1, Math.min(input.length(), 4)));
        }`. One only needs to ensure the length is greater than one.

Comment: @KevinO good one. I liked you solution.

Comment: @KevinO I have applied your suggestion to the answer thanks.